# Differentiating between Hard and Soft Dependencies

Tags: fedora, yum, package-management

I will ask this with an example -

I have installed gnash-plugin on fedora 64 bit with Yum. It pulled in following packages -

```
  Installing     : agg-2.5-9.fc13.x86_64                                                                                                             1/6 
  Installing     : gtkglext-libs-1.2.0-10.fc12.x86_64                                                                                                2/6 
  Installing     : boost-thread-1.44.0-7.fc14.x86_64                                                                                                 3/6 
  Installing     : boost-date-time-1.44.0-7.fc14.x86_64                                                                                              4/6 
  Installing     : 1:gnash-0.8.8-4.fc14.x86_64                                                                                                       5/6 
  Installing     : 1:gnash-plugin-0.8.8-4.fc14.x86_64                                                                                                6/6
```

Now, I tested the plugin and I didn't like it. I want to remove all these above packages which got installed with the plugin as I don't longer going to need them. How can I do this?

I checked remove-with-plugin for yum but it pulls in all the packages which are currently depending on the packages.

I understand the thought process behind showing what packages are getting affected - but I am wondering if there is any way of looking at the history with what package got installed when I installed a certain package.

When gnash-plugin wasn't there firefox was running fine with but after I installation firefox is now depends on this new plugin.

Has any one worked on differentiating hard-dependencies(hard means the program will break if that package is not there) and soft-dependencies ( soft means the program may not get affected fatally) ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on supported version of Fedora, you can just do:

```
yum history list gnash
```

...and then:

```
yum history undo <transaction id>
```

...if you get the very latest yum (Eg. from the yum-rawhide rebuild repo. on [repos.fedorapeople.org](http://repos.fedorapeople.org)) then you can also do:

```
yum remove gnash --setopt=clean_requirements_on_remove=true
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu/Debian land we implement "hard/soft" dependencies by having actual *Depends* but also *Recommends*. We also have *Suggests* which are even softer soft dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

[Debian and derivatives have hard/medium/soft dependencies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6996/differentiating-between-hard-and-soft-dependencies/6997#6997), but that doesn't solve your problem.

[APT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool), the Debian equivalent of Yum, distinguishes between *manually installed* and *automatically installed* packages, which solves your problem (automatically installed packages are removed if no manually installed package depends on them). I don't know if this feature has been ported to Yum.

Comment: Unless you are using **aptitude**, this doesn't happen by default. Your removal/purging command will look like `apt-get --auto-remove remove/purge`